# Is there a way to convert FlutterQuill to HTML content?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
var json = jsonEncode(_controller.document.toDelta().toJson());
```

Do we have a Dart plugin for converting [FlutterQuill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) to HTML  content?

Comment: (This question is associated with [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420496/you-have-too-many-pending-edits-further-edits-cannot-be-submitted-until-prior-e#comment927757_420496) - likely to be automatically deleted and then only visible for users with more than 10,000 reputation points.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently there was an issue in their GitHub account and someone found [a workaround](https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/issues/15#issuecomment-817199346) via Markdown.

But keep in mind that it is not entirely correct yet and as far as I know there isn't any straightforward conversion into HTML yet.

Another thing you can try is to create a fork of the [zefyr HTML editor](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr), use their Delta converter, and update it to work with Quill deltas. I tried that for myself. It worked in simple cases, but in our project there were harder cases, so we ditched this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using packages *[delta_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/delta_markdown)* and *[markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/markdown)*:

You may want to convert your delta to HTML with a method like so:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:delta_markdown/delta_markdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/models/quill_delta.dart';
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart';

String quillDeltaToHtml(Delta delta) {
  final convertedValue = jsonEncode(delta.toJson());
  final markdown = deltaToMarkdown(convertedValue);
  final html = markdownToHtml(markdown);

  return html;
}
```

You can learn an alternative solution that needs to be implemented in [FlutterQuill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) on this issue: *[Support conversion of Delta to HTML and Markdown #15](https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/issues/15)*

Comment: Tried this workaround. This is working but some of the attributes such as colour,backgroundColor,quote, blockCode in quill delta is not converting into Html.

Comment: any solution for attributes such as colour,backgroundColor ?

Comment: Any solution to the colors, quote, and others?